# Woocommerce restrict viewing products and show message. Without redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hoping someone can help. I currently have `woocommerce` with `wcvendors` installed. Products are hidden from non-vendors by using a redirect to the login. I would like to remove this redirect and just have users without permission see a message. I looked at plugins with no luck. When a non-vendor click on a product they should get a little message. Currently, I have 1000's of redirects and it cant be a good thing.

Here is my current redirect code where you can see how `wcvndors` calls out vendors. 
Just hoping someone has a code or can point me in the right direction,

I like how facebook does it when not logged in, a modal pops up that can be x'ed out. Thanks

```
    function wpse_131562_redirect() {
if (!WCV_Vendors::is_vendor(get_current_user_id())
        && (is_product() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect("/my-account/");
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
    function wpse_131562_redirect() {
if (!WCV_Vendors::is_vendor(get_current_user_id())
        && (is_product() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(home_url()."/my-account/");
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

Comment: I think thats the same code I posted, a redirect code. Im trying to find something that wouldn't redirect, but display a message to non vendors instead. Thanks